# PHP file_get_contents from URL with PORT

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) `file_get_contents()`. But the URL I'm trying to open use a port, for example:

```
file_get_contents("http://212.21.323.32:8010")
```

I'm not able to open this URL, how can I do this?

Comment: That's not a valid ip-address.

Comment: First enable error reporting because PHP tells you what is going wrong. Always trouble-shoot in case something unplanned happened. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: As well as not being a valid IP address, that is also not a valid URL because it does not have a path component. At minimum it would need a trailing slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and use `CURLOPT_PORT` to set the port you want to connect on.

```
<?php
$cURL = curl_init('http://www.google.co.uk'); //Initialise cURL with the URL to connect to
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PORT, 80); //Set the port to connect to
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //Get cURL to return the HTML from the curl_exec function

$HTML = curl_exec($cURL); //Execute the request and store the result in $HTML

echo $HTML; //Output the HTML
?>
```

Comment: Maybe nothing, but if he's having trouble with `file_get_contents`, using `cURL` will at least give him some options to play with.

Comment: he's having troubles with wrong IP :-)

Comment: Either that or there's a 9th bit in the 3rd octet I didn't know about :p

Comment: 3rd argument of the 2nd `curl_setopt` should be `true` not `80`, although with PHP's loose typing, that would work fine. `curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

Comment: @JoelMellon Good spot, fixed