# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, curl, file-get-contents

I am trying to use IP address to get file_get_contents

```
  $url = "http://82.33.33.100:8001"; // Ip address, it example IP address. ( not correct ip address here)
    $data =file_get_contents($url);
```

I am getting following error:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in /var/www/html/test.php on line 10

I installed Apache on Ubuntu. If I use google.com and it's working fine. If I use **CURL** I got **NO ROUTE** Error.

Any idea?

Comment: not a valid ip address

Comment: its dummy ip address

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your HTTP request, it's the server-side where there's an error.

Comment: what error any idea. please

Comment: /var/www/html/test.php is on the same server (ip 82.33.33.100) or another server?

Comment: this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990557/php-file-get-contents-from-url-with-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990557/php-file-get-contents-from-url-with-port) ?